# How can I install Gnat Programming Studio (GPS) on Mac?

Tags: ide, installation, ada, gnat

I managed to install the GNAT compiler from *libre.adacore.com* on a [OS X v10.6.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard). I also would like to install the Gnat Programming Studio (GPS) environment. I tried different things, but none of them worked and I didn't find any exhaustive explanation.

How can I perform (possibly step by step) the installation of GPS on a OS X operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose my solution for [Mac OS X v10.6.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard).
Since I had problems with the `adagpl-2014` version, I downloaded the `adagpl-2012` version.

To install it, open the terminal in Utilities and navigate to the folder

`/x86_64-darwin/adagpl-2012/gnatgpl`

and launch the file `doinstall` with the command `sudo ./doinstall`.

Be sure to wait until the installation ends. After that, navigate to the subfolder bin and launch the GPS file with `./gps`.

Answer (score 2):

GPS needs [XQuartz](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) ([X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) support for Mac OS X). Earlier versions of GPS actually run under X11; GNAT GPL 2014’s GPS doesn’t need it to run, but it still requires a `libpng` from XQuartz.

GPS is already present in the installation, in the same `bin/` directory as the other programs (`gnatmake` etc), which should be on your `PATH`. So, in a terminal window,

```
gps &
```

should do the trick.

One of the members of the [GNAT-OSX mailing list](http://hermes.gwu.edu/archives/gnat-osx.html) posted [a simple `GPS.app`](https://hermes.gwu.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1406&L=gnat-osx&F=&S=&P=342) to run GPS like any other application from the [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)).

Comment: actually Xquartz is installed by default. You are right, it is sufficient to lunch the gps file in the bin directory. Actually the command is `./gps`.
The problem is that gnat 2014 seems to be incompatible with mac 10.6.8.
I downloaded the 2012 version and it is ok.
Thanks a lot by the way.